# DE Undetermined Coefficient; coefficients sum to zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question is:

Find a particular solution of the differential equation:
y'''' + 2y''+ y = 3 sin x − 5 cos x

My guess for yp is Asinx+Bcosx. When I differentiate and plug in, I get (A+A-2A)sinx+(2B-B-B)cosx. What kind of trick question is this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the general solution is $y=(Ax+B) \cos x +(Cx+D) \sin x$ where $A,B,C,D$ are arbitary constants. So it is little wonder that you are slightly baffled when you try to use this a test solution to the particular integral.

Try a solution of the form $y =E x^2 \cos x + F x^2 \sin x$ and see how you get on.